# Cannot import functions from google.py

Tags: python

I'm trying to import a function from a file with name `google.py` in my cwd. If I drop into the interpreter I can import the file just fine, but importing google and running `dir()` on the imported object returns none of the attributes I've defined, and returns some I haven't defined:

```
>>> import google
>>> dir(google)
['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'logging']
```

I tried `pip uninstall google` but even after that ran I'm not able to see my functions on the imported google object.

Does anyone know what might explain this behavior? Running:

```
help(google.logging)
```

returns an enigmatic response:

```
Help on package google.logging in google:

NAME
    google.logging

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    type (package)

FILE
    (built-in)
```

Any pointers others can offer on this query would be very helpful!

Comment: So if you rename `google.py` to say, `test.py`, and then you `import test` and `dir(test)`, you get the same results?

Comment: Oh no if I rename google.py to test.py I can `from test import job` but I want to `from google import job`

Comment: `print(google.__path__)` should tell you where the imported module or package is really located.

Comment: Ah! I had tried `.__file__` which returned nothing, but `__path__` works

Comment: Do you all have any thoughts on why `pip uninstall google` wouldn't remove this? Is it because the pip uninstall command uses the egg namespace and the egg namespace might not be identical to the package namespace?

Comment: The documentation of `pip` notes that `pip is able to uninstall most installed packages. Known exceptions are:
Pure distutils packages installed with python setup.py install, which leave behind no metadata to determine what files were installed.

Script wrappers installed by python setup.py develop.` (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_uninstall/)